# Render the detailed page when clicking on a linked item on the sidebar menu

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

I am working on the sidebar. Currently, I have a few items on my sidebar. When I select an item, it shows a few details on the main area. Actually, I have a large amount of data that I want to show on a selected sidebar item. The data might be different for each sidebar item. I think a react component rendering is a good option to display the data but I am confused about how to achieve this. I am sharing my full [code](https://codesandbox.io/s/my-react-components-library-qcnijg?file=/src/routes/invoice.tsx:109-116) here to understand it.

**Invoices**

```
import { NavLink, Outlet, useSearchParams } from 'react-router-dom';
import { getInvoices } from '../data';

export default function Invoices() {
    let invoices = getInvoices();
    let [searchParams, setSearchParams] = useSearchParams();

    return (
        <div style={{ display: 'flex' }}>
            <nav
                style={{
                    borderRight: 'solid 1px',
                    padding: '1rem',
                }}>
                <input // search input
                    value={searchParams.get('filter') || ''}
                    onChange={(event) => {
                        let filter = event.target.value;
                        if (filter) {
                            setSearchParams({ filter });
                        } else {
                            setSearchParams({});
                        }
                    }}
                />

                {invoices // set search params
                    .filter((invoice) => {
                        let filter = searchParams.get('filter');
                        if (!filter) return true;
                        let name = invoice.name.toLowerCase();
                        return name.startsWith(filter.toLowerCase());
                    })
                    .map((
                        invoice // active list color
                    ) => (
                        <NavLink
                            style={({ isActive }) => {
                                return {
                                    display: 'block',
                                    margin: '1rem 0',
                                    color: isActive ? 'red' : '',
                                };
                            }}
                            to={`/invoices/${invoice.anumber}`}
                            key={invoice.anumber}>
                            {invoice.name}
                        </NavLink>
                    ))}
            </nav>
            <Outlet />
        </div>
    );
}
```

please find whole code in the link

Comment: The code in the sandbox appears to be working. What exactly is the issue or question here?

Comment: yes, the code is working. When I click on a list item it just shows 3 records. I want to render a component with a lot more information. look this site as an example. https://korkortonline.se/en/theory/

Comment: Is there something stopping you from rendering more information? I still don't see or understand what any issue is.

Comment: currently, I am rendering plain text from data.ts. I want to render a full page of data that should be included images and other items, I show an example in my last comment. I am looking for a solution that I can render components rather than plain text. I hope you will understand now

Comment: I guess that's what I don't understand. You can render whatever you like/need. Is there something keeping you from being able to do this?

Comment: Thank you so much for your time. I will solve it

Comment: @ahmad
Have you solved your question yet?

Comment: @Tung
 Not yet. I started working on another branch and still working on that.

Answer (score 0):

I have gone through that [tutorial](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/getting-started/tutorial) which is the same as your code. If I were you, I will redesign the `getInvoice` method to fetch the corresponding item from your database. The item from the database should be as text or blob to store a large amount of data such as text or media including URLs, images and video links. As you know, the `getInvoice` method in the tutorial is simplified by returning a bit of text while yours could be more complex to fetch the appropriate data from the data warehouse or something along those lines.

For example:

```
export default function Invoice() {
  let params = useParams();
  let invoice = getInvoice(parseInt(params.invoiceId, 10));
  return (
    // here is your logic implementation
  );
```

I hope that would be helpful.